# Case Sensitive Sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a sumifs formula where it is case-sensitive. For example I need to sumifs with three criteria, the first two are not case sensitive but the third is and i'm not sure how to add it in. The data is in a random order on a different page with the case sensitive parts all jumbled together. I basically need to differentiate between Product and PRODUCT. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT` combined with `ISNUMBER` and `FIND` which is case sensitive.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("PRODUCT",$A$1:$A$100))),$B$1:$B$100)
```

You can incorporate the other two criterion into the `SUMPRODUCT` as well.